# Sum two sum queries in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have two sum queries

```
SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN re.ReApType = 'Allocation' AND re.ReAppType = 'E' AND re.YearID = '2015'
            THEN re.ReCapitalAmount + re.ReRevenueAmount
        ELSE
            0 
    END
) AS RevisedAllocationExcess,
SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN re.ReApType = 'Allocation' AND re.ReAppType = 'S' AND re.YearID = '2015' 
            THEN re.ReCapitalAmount + re.ReRevenueAmount
        ELSE
            0 
    END
) AS RevisedAllocationSurrender
```

I want to sum these two queries. Please tell me how to sum them up and show the resut in some third column. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `SUM` of both columns, modify the `CASE` expression:

```
SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN re.ReApType = 'Allocation' AND re.ReAppType IN('E','S') AND re.YearID = '2015' 
            THEN re.ReCapitalAmount + re.ReRevenueAmount
        ELSE
            0 
    END
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that part of code into a subquery:

```
select
  t.RevisedAllocationExcess,
  t.RevisedAllocationSurrender,
  t.RevisedAllocationExcess + t.RevisedAllocationSurrender as RevisedTotal
from
(
  select
    ...
    SUM(...) as RevisedAllocationExcess,
    SIM(...) as RevisedAllocationSurrender
) t
```

or CTE:

```
;with cteReviseTotals as
(
  select
    ...
    SUM(...) as RevisedAllocationExcess,
    SIM(...) as RevisedAllocationSurrender
)
select
  t.RevisedAllocationExcess,
  t.RevisedAllocationSurrender,
  t.RevisedAllocationExcess + t.RevisedAllocationSurrender as RevisedTotal
from cteReviseTotals t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN re.ReApType = 'Allocation' AND re.ReAppType = 'E' AND re.YearID = '2015'
            THEN re.ReCapitalAmount + re.ReRevenueAmount
        ELSE
            0 
    END
) AS RevisedAllocationExcess,
SUM(
    CASE 
        WHEN re.ReApType = 'Allocation' AND re.ReAppType = 'S' AND re.YearID = '2015' 
            THEN re.ReCapitalAmount + re.ReRevenueAmount
        ELSE
            0 
    END
) AS RevisedAllocationSurrender,
RevisedAllocationExcess+RevisedAllocationSurrender RevisedSum
```

Hopes this helps...